# Как развернуть React Native с Expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-native

Выполнил команду `npm install exp`. Папка node_modules создалась и
Получил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потом написал команду: `exp init Application. В итоге "exp" command not found.

Как же начать работать с Expo? Почему команда exp init не выполняется?

Comment: `sudo npm i exp` – от администратора нужно cli ставить

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: super user do node package manager install expo ;) то, что устанавливается как отдельная команда в консоль устанавливается не локально в проект, а глобально в систему, поэтому необходимо sudo

Comment: сделал эту команду, ввел пароль рута, а после команды exp init App всё равно "exp" not found

Comment: сделал повторно, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-app // ставим глобально CRNA, в нём по умолчанию всё заточено для работы с expo
$ create-react-native-app my-project // создаем проект
$ cd my-project
$ npm start // запускаем его
```

с CRNA всё предельно просто https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html